# Express - запуск сервера независимо от сессии

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Каким образом можно запустить проект на node.js (использую express.js как основной фреймворк), чтобы он работал в background'е и не зависел от сессии юзера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы отключаетесь, все запущенные в вашем сеансе процессы убиваются.
Вам нужно запустить ноду как демона

Варианты:

1. Воспользоваться модулем вроде [forever](http://npmjs.com/forever) или [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).
2. [Nohup](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) `nohup node app.js > output.log &`
3. [Screen](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/screen) - терминал, который не умрёт когда вы отключитесь

Comment: Спасибо, друг. Forever то что надо =)