# Запуск приложений под nodejs на нескольких доменах и без остановки после выхода с Putty

Tags: node.js

Начал знакомиться с nodejs и возникают первые вопросы. В этой теме два из них.

**Вопрос #1.** Если предположим у меня в аккаунте виртуального хостинга в cPanel'e есть несколько разных доменов например один основной, к которому прикреплен аккаунт и файлы которого находятся в директории public_html, и кроме него могу создать еще несколько дополнительных, под которые создаются отдельные папки.

В каждом домене предположим будет свое js-приложение под nodejs. Как правильно запустить каждое приложение на его домене чтобы они все работали и рендерили каждый свои страницы? Если запускаю приложение на каком то одном домене, то оно почему то работает на всех доменах одно и то же.

**Вопрос #2.** Как запустить nodejs чтобы страницы, которые рендерят js-приложения, открывались даже после выхода с Putty? Когда нахожусь в терминале то страницы открываются но когда выхожу, то перестают рендериться.

Пробовал

```
nohup node app.js &
```

и файл nohup.out создается, но после выхода с Putty страницы все равно перестают открываться.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос #2: используйте модуль  `pm2`

Comment: [Вопрос #2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777656/express-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8/777668#777668)

Comment: Ребята, а в чем разница между pm2 и forever ?