# Как запустить node js как службу windows?

Tags: node.js

Есть файл node js (web-server.js) который должен быть всегда запущен, даже после перезагрузки. 
Как это лучше реализовать? Как то установить его как службу или есть другие решения?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777656/express-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8/777668#777668

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service